# Not able to use coords attribute in HTML

Tags: html

I was reading anchor tag in detail where in i came across the coords attribute.
I was testing this attribute by writing the foloowing code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com"  coords="42,59">Youtube</a>
<a href="http://wwww.google.com"  coords="12,19">google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to place the links (youtube and google ) at some fixed coordiantes using the coords attribute. But i am not getting the desired results. it shows the result as it would show without using the coords.

Is it possible to use coords to place links at a particular position??

If not whats the other way to do so?

Comment: You could use a combination of `z-index`, `position`, `top`, `left` css attributes for these elements.

Comment: Only the `<area>` element has a `coords` attribute. What documentation are you reading that claims it belongs to anchors?

Answer (score 0):

The `coords`-Attribute was intended to define regions (not positions) within the `<map>`-Element, e.g. make regions of an image clickable.
Even when there are some browsers that support direct use achors in maps
the right way would be to use `<area>` elements within the map.

In order to position elements absolutely you should use css like so:

```css
#ytb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  left: 59px;
}

#ggl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 19px;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.youtube.com" id="ytb">Youtube</a>
<a href="http://wwww.google.com" id="ggl">google</a>
```